# Gtk events differences

Tags: gtk

Can someone tell me the difference of the events in GTK:

```
on_treeview_button_press_event()

on_treeview_key_press_event()

on_treeview_cursor_changed()
```

Answer (score 4):

"The differences?" They are different events, i.e. they are generated for different reasons.

Also, those names are confusing, as only the last one is local to the GtkTreeView widget, the first two are generic GtkWidget-level signals.

The documentation states:

GtkWidget's [button-press-event](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event):

> The ::button-press-event signal will be emitted when a button (typically from a mouse) is pressed.

GtkWidget's [key-press-event](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-press-event):

> The ::key-press-event signal is emitted when a key is pressed.

GtkTreeView's [cursor-changed](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#GtkTreeView-cursor-changed):

> The position of the cursor (focused cell) has changed.

Comment: I create a treeview window and i add button-press-event and cursor-changed event, i just find every time when i clicked in the window, there are these two events. Even i click in the same place, so i do not quite understand why. So i wonder if i want to call a fonction when i click in the treeview, i can use either of the two fonction.